# how to Scheduled Notifications in Android on a specified time with TimePicker on android studio

Tags: java, android, timepicker

i want to send reminder on selected time using time picker from my application automatically or to activate particulate class on user selected time.

here is my code

```
public class Time_Picker extends Activity {
    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog,buttonCancelAlarm;;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;
    private String format = "";

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timepicker);

        myTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        myTimePicker.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        myTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
        buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
                openTimePickerDialog(false);

            }
        });
        buttonCancelAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        buttonCancelAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                cancelAlarm();
            }
        });

    }
    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(myTimePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                myTimePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 00);

            setAlarm(cal);
    }

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){
        textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                "\n\n***\n"
                        + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                        + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

here is my AlaramReciver.java

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) arg0.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);

        Intent i = new Intent(arg0, DailyReport_CSV_file.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        arg0.startActivity(i);
    }
```

timepicker.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#0a608e"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gobackb"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            tools:targetApi="honeycomb"
            android:src="@drawable/whitearrows"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Daily report dispatch time"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
        android:text="Set daily report dispatch time "
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#074363"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TimePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startSetDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Target Time"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel Alarm"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alarmprompt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to activate a class on user selected time on time picker

Answer (score 0):

```
    **To start an activity context is needed. You can start activity inside broadcast receiver and also you have to set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag in intent**    

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(arg0, Activity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    arg0.startActivity(i);

            }

        }
```